# How do I make my application installable via Yum package manager?

Tags: linux, yum, package-managers

I'm trying to learn how to build an installer with Yum (as opposed to apt, port, brew, etc).

I can't seem to find any clear resources on this. What steps would I need to take to do it for my own application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yum is installing rpm packages from a repository. So basically, you need to package your app via rpm and then publish it in some repository, which is usually a folder accessed via http/ftp.

[The rather old documentation](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Core/3/html/Software_Management_Guide/sn-managing-repositories.html) contains the basic informations you will want to read on yum repositories.

The much more complicated process is to create an installable rpm package, which is documented [here](http://www.rpm.org/).

One simple way to host your own repository is [fedorapeople.org](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Fedorapeople_Repos)